# Magento 2: How to create observer for adding data to table after order

Tags: magento2

Magento2: How to create observer for adding data to table after order.

Comment: Did you give a try to that event to save your fields value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an observer at event "sales_order_save_after".

Add etc/events.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="unique_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddCustomFieldValue"  />        
</config>
```

Add logic to save required field value in file Observer\AddCustomFieldValue.php